# How to deal with my sharepoint datetime control css?

Tags: css, sharepoint

I'm developing sharepoint datetime control and got some problem with css of this control.
below is my html code.

```
<td style="padding-top: -10px">
     <SharePoint:DateTimeControl CalendarImageUrl="/_layouts/NCS.OCP.Resource/images/calendar.jpg"
                                                        DatePickerFrameUrl="/_layouts/iframe.aspx" ID="DateDOB" DateOnly="true" Calendar="Gregorian"
                                                        LocaleId="2057" runat="server"></SharePoint:DateTimeControl>
        <td>
```

I have tried modify ms-input css with padding-top -10px but failed, this control always falls down of my td.

is there any way to pull this control up so that this td can on one line...?
[image]

Comment: try aligning other controls to botton in td.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like sharepoint has it's own `<div>`s or `<td>`s. Maybe even some custom css/
Try inspecting the elements, getting their ID's and then changing it with JS.